# Using MGF's to characterize a distribution

Tags: probability-theory, probability-distributions, moment-generating-functions

> Let $X_1,X_2,X_3$ be independent such that for all $x > 0$,
>
> $$ P(|X_i| > x) < e^{-x}, \;\;\; i = 1,2,3 $$
>
> Prove that if $X_1+X_3$ and $X_2+X_3$ have the same distribution, then so does $X_1$ and $X_2$.

Because of the condition given, I assumed the question meant for us to use moment generating functions. Since $X_1+X_3$ and $X_2+X_3$ have the same distribution, their MGFs are equal for all $t$,

$$ \phi_{X_1}(t)\phi_{X_3}(t) = \phi_{X_1+X_3}(t) = \phi_{X_2+X_3}(t) = \phi_{X_2}(t)\phi_{X_3}(t)$$

where the first and last equalities come from the independence assumptions. EDIT: If I can show that $\phi_{X_3}(t)$ **is finite** in a neighbourhood of $0$, say $(-\delta,\delta)$, then $\phi_{X_1}(t) = \phi_{X_2}(t)$ for all $t \in (-\delta,\delta)$. By the [uniqueness theorem](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/297243/167900), this would imply that the distributions of $X_1$ and $X_2$ are the same.

EDIT: To prove finiteness, first suppose $t > 0$. Then,

$$ E[e^{tX_3}] = \int_0^\infty P(e^{tX_3}>x)dx = \int_0^\infty P\left(X_3 > \frac{1}{t}\ln(x)\right)dx \leq 1 + \int_1^\infty x^{-\frac{1}{t}}dx $$

The above is finite when $t<1$. We can do something similar when $t < 0$.

Comment: Non-vanishing is rather trivial; $e^{tX_3}$ is a strictly positive random variable, so its expectation is also positive. This is one good advantage of MGF over CF. Rather, MGF often suffers from blowing-up, i.e. MGF can take value $+\infty$, which is neither good. The exponential bound of tail is required to guarantee that this does not happen around a neighborhood of $0$ at least.

Comment: @SangchulLee Ahh, my apologies for not seeing something so trivial. But I guess I still have to prove that MGF is finite in a neighbourhood of $0$ using the condition.